# Is this transcoding the video?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an application used in government and subject to regulation that prevents transcoding or altering the video quality in any way.

I’m attempting to utilize FFmpeg to change a video into an MP4 by copying the raw streams to a new container.

This is the command being used:

`ffmpeg.exe -y -i INPUT.ASF -c:av copy OUTPUT.MP4`

Notice the `-c:av copy`. The FFmpeg documentation says, “a special value copy (output only) to indicate that the stream is not to be re-encoded.“

Visually the videos before and after appear to be identical quality with no pixelation on the ships.

**Is this altering the video quality or could this be considered transcoding?**

Comment: what's your console output? It'll tell you in there, it's just tricky to find...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a syntax error but other than that, yes, `copy` will avoid transcoding of the stream. The hitch is that the output container may not support all codecs that the input container does.

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -i INPUT.ASF -c copy OUTPUT.MP4
```

Your current command was transcoding the video since ffmpeg's parser only consumes the first character in stream type i.e. `-c:av` is treated as `-c:a`. `-c copy` will copy all stream types. Use `-c:v copy -c:a copy` to separately set codec mode for video and audio.